# Copying List of Files(with spaces in path) in .txt file to a Folder

Tags: bash, macos, unix, cp

I need to copy some files separated line by line from a text file to a folder.

I have used the following command

```
cat list.txt | xargs -J % cp % folder
```

Since the file path has spaces in between, a File not found exception is thrown.How can I overcome this issue?

Please advice.

Comment: give sample data from list.txt, you can set the delim on xargs. Also is that J supposed to be an I?

Comment: @123 This a sample from list.txt `/Volumes/Data/my 3 data backup/Camera/P_2535_133507_vHDR_Auto.jpg`

Comment: @123 I assume that the command is using `BSD xargs` instead of `GNU xargs` which has option `-J` instead of `-I` when specifying the replacement string

Answer (score 2):

`GNU parallel` is also a good alternative to `xargs`, it handles input arguments well even when special characters (spaces, quotes) exists

```
$ cat list.txt | parallel cp {} folder/
```

Comment: @techno Since it is not installed on mac osx by default, you can use `brew install parallel` to install it if you have homebrew

Answer (score -1):

try the following:

```
IFS=$'\n' && for i in $(cat list.txt); do cp "$i" folder/; done
```

Comment: Code only answers might solve the issue, but some explanation of how it solves the problem would help in learning to understand how to solve future problems.